# Lodash remove from string array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of string and want to instantly remove some of them. But it doesn't work

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
_.remove(list, 'b');
console.log(list); // 'b' still there
```

I guess it happened because `_.remove` function accept string as second argument and considers that is property name. How to make lodash do an equality check in this case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One more option for you is to use _.pull, which unlike _.without, does not create a copy of the array, but only modifies it instead:

```
_.pull(list, 'b'); // ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Reference: https://lodash.com/docs#pull

Answer (score 6):

As Giuseppe Pes points out, `_.remove` is expecting a function.  A more direct way to do what you want is to use `_.without` instead, which *does* take elements to remove directly.

```
_.without(['a','b','c','d'], 'b');  //['a','c','d']
```

Answer (score 3):

Function _.remove doesn't accept a string as second argument but a predicate function which is called for each value in the array. If the function returns `true` the value is removed from the array.

Lodas doc: https://lodash.com/docs#remove

> Removes all elements from array that predicate returns truthy for and
>   returns an array of the removed elements. The predicate is bound to
>   thisArg and invoked with three arguments: (value, index, array).

So, if you want to remove `b` from your array you should something like this:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
_.remove(list, function(v) { return v === 'b'; });
["a", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: The return value should be v == 'b', not v !== 'b'

Comment: @trevor no. That would match only `b`. We want the opposite

Comment: I think they just wanted to remove 'b' based on the comment in their code: 'b still there'

Comment: Yes, I want to remove 'b' from my list. So here should be equal expression

Comment: Also, I found that `_.without` does exactly what I need, but create a copy of array

Comment: This is the write code if you want to remove `b` because if the value is `b` the expression returns `false` and the value is removed.

Comment: The condition you currently have in your code ( return v !== 'b' ) actually removes everything except for 'b'. Run a test of your code in your browser.